# Check if applied migrations match the DbContext?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I want to create a unit test to ensure no developer will commit model changes without the corresponding migration.

How do I test that the database matches the DbContext?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can leverage some of the lower-level Migrations components to do that:

```
var migrationsAssembly = db.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>();
var differ = db.GetService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>();

var hasDifferences = differ.HasDifferences(
    migrationsAssembly.ModelSnapshot.Model,
    db.Model);

Assert.False(hasDifferences, "You forgot to add a migration!");
```

Comment: Note, this doesn't actually check the database. To do that, see [this comment](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6214#issuecomment-332980580) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does that work with an in memory database?

Comment: You mean with the in-memory EF Core provider? No; `IMigrationsAssembly` and `IMigrationsModelDiffer` are only available on relational providers. (But if you mean in in-memory SQLite database, yes.)

Comment: How can I find out the exact differences? If I do `add-migration [...]` the generated Migration is empty but the code above returns `true`

Comment: @AlexanderHerold there is `differ.GetDifferences()` for getting the changes.

Comment: Is this possible to do only via CLI?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell No, but please upvote issue [#22105](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22105).

Answer (score 1):

Based on @bricelam's answer I created a generic method to test for applied migrations.

```
private static void ShouldMatchContext<T>()
  where T : DbContext
{
  using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:"))
  {
    connection.Open();
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>();
    var db = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), builder.UseSqlite(connection).Options) as T;

    db.Database.EnsureCreated();

    var migrationsAssembly = db.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>();
    var differ = db.GetService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>();

    bool hasDifferences = differ.HasDifferences(migrationsAssembly.ModelSnapshot?.Model, db.Model);

    Assert.False(hasDifferences);
  }
}
```