# Entity Framework Core: Detect changes in model

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I have model

```
public class BBDB
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [CanBeNull]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And added new property. My model become:

```
public class BBDB
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [CanBeNull]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

I need to check using dbcontext that this changes exist.
So, ".ChangeTracker.HasChanges()" doesn't allow me to do this. Add-migration create code to make changes.
How can I check that we have changes?

Comment: Entity Framework v7 ==> Entity Framework Core ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131347/check-if-there-are-any-pending-changes-to-be-saved

Comment: Probably this does? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091587/check-if-applied-migrations-match-the-dbcontext

Comment: Yes, but i need .net framework
This solution is for .net Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok
It is very easy in the end...

```
Context.Database.Initialize
```

This solve our problem
If there are changes in model that we don't migrate, it crashes with message:

> System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException: Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration